# Deterministic navigation of c++ class tags in VIM. ctags doesn't work well

Tags: vim, c++, vim-plugins, ctags

Currently, to navigate `a.run()` tag, I put the cursor on `run` and press `g]`, which opens a window with enumerated list of tags for all files that have `run()`. I have to manually find an option that corresponds to `run()` in `A` class. I'd like vim to find that association for me.

It seems that clang has this type of capabilities. it works pretty well with auto-completion (clang_complete).

Is there a plug-in that has this functionality? or how do people go around it?

Comment: SO would have been a better choice as this question is oriented toward the customization of a development environment, and more importantly, clang users are over there -> they may know how the information you (we actually) are looking for can be obtained.

Comment: @LucHermitte do you know if i should re-post there or is there a way to transfer the question?

Comment: I've seen a lot of vim questions transferred from SO to here, but never the other way around. Ideally, moving it would be the best thing to do. But it's up to "moderators" to estimate here is not the correct place. This is unfortunately a recurring subject.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the tool clang_complete uses is only able to return a list of matching functions for completion. Nothing more.

However, I've seen another plugin for vim: clang_indexer that may help. I haven't spend much time investigating what it can do.

HTH.